# How to resolve a git-svn rebase with moved files?

Tags: git, svn, merge, git-svn, rebase

I have a problem rebasing my long-lived branch (called 'metrics') onto the latest version of my 'trunk' branch. The goal is to get my changes rebased, and then committed back to SVN.

The rebase has 75 steps right now, and step 40 is applying significant source code changes onto files that were relocated in svn.

Specifically, I made lots of changes to files in /java/**/*.java. Meanwhile, these files were relocated to: /src/main/java/**/*.java.

git status shows:

```
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   added by them:      java/StripesResources.properties
.... (many files like this)
#   both deleted:       src/StripesResources.properties
.... (many files like this)
#   added by us:        src/main/java/StripesResources.properties
.... (many files like this)
```

There are over 900 files in this state, what do I do to merge them? Not all of them have substantial changes.

I tried moving / copying the 'them' versions of the files (my changes) onto the 'us' locations (where they should be), but that didn't seem to work.

Should I use 'git mv' in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a difficult problem.  I think before you can merge your branch, you might have to change the history of (a copy of) it so that the files are moved to new the locations in trunk before the updates you made are applied.

Comment: unfortunately, the files already _are_ in the correct locations. It looks like I already merged (not rebased) these changes from trunk into my 'metrics' stream, so the files are already in the correct locations. But git doesn't seem to recognize that.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how the merge gets cleaned up-- if you can do it and get the changes in the index, you should be able to continue the rebase.  If git is really confused at this point, you might have to fall back to writing a script to do a file-by-file merge from a copy of the two trees (using diff3 for example) into the rebasing tree and doing a git mv to put the merged files where they should be after.

Answer (score 1):

This might not the best solution as it involves history revision. You could use `git filter-branch` to move the 'metrics' branch's `/java/**/*.java` files into `/src/main/java/**/*.java`, then conduct the rebase. First, backup your repository. Then try something like this:

```
git checkout metrics
git filter-branch --index-filter '
    git ls-files -s |
        perl -pe "s{\t/java/\"?}{\t/src/main/java/}" |
        GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info &&
    mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new $GIT_INDEX_FILE
' HEAD
```

That will rewrite your metric branch's history, effectively moving every file whose path begins with `/java/` to `/src/main/java`. If you want just the java files in those paths, modify the `perl` statement accordingly. Mucking around with `git ls-files -s | perl -pe <substitution>` at various points in your history will help you determine what you need.

A a Thing That Can Be Done With Git (tm), the above is awfully drastic. All the same, it should solve the file name issue. Having attempted a few long-divergent branch merges before, this particular problem will not be your last. If your workflow generates highly divergent, long-term branches regularly, you might consider changing it.